# What does "ByteLo" mean in user agent?

Tags: user-agent, inappbrowser, tiktok

I am trying to detect if a user is on tiktok in-app browser.
Please check the images below.

1. user agent on tiktok in-app browser from iOS device
   [image: user agent from iOS device]
2. user agent on tiktok in-app browser from Android device
   [image: user agent from Android device]

From the first image, I can assume that a user is on tiktok in-app browser since there's a word "Btyedance" which is a parent company of tiktok.

Meanwhile, there is a word "ByteLo" in the second image. and I am not sure if it also implies it's tiktok's or if it means something else.

Can I assume if a user is on tiktok in-app browser from the word, "ByteLo"?

Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your user agent string is likely getting clipped due to a character limit somewhere along the way. (e.g. in your database, or your HTTP header parsing)

TikTok includes the user's locale (e.g. `ByteLocale/en`) in the User Agent of its in-app browser web views, which is where the `ByteLo` is likely coming from.